# How to know the number of trials to open lock?

Tags: probability

A drunk has five keys on his key chain, and only one will open the front door of his
house. He tries each key until he finds the right one. Assume that he is so drunk that he
may repeat the wrong key any number of times. On average how many trials he will
make to open the front lock of his house.

Comment: A more interesting version of the problem: [Drunk man with a set of keys.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2044007/318073).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [6 keys and a door( probabilities)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781073/6-keys-and-a-door-probabilities) or this? [What's the Probability of a drunk man open a door with n possible keys?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2760572/318073). It appears the same question was asked multiple times on the site already...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [5 keys and lock](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621864/5-keys-and-lock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Consider  Bernoulli trials with $p=1/5$.
Then you are looking for the expected No. of trials till reaching the first success.
That' a [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)